# Security risk having undefined variable

Tags: php, security

What's the security issue having

```
    <?php
    $var = $_GET['var'];
    if ($variable)
    {
            // sensitive data
    }
```

is it possible that the attacker can get to sensitive data somehow?

Comment: What kind of sensitive data is in there in what form?

Comment: I guess you mean `if($var)` ;)

Comment: `$variable` is not defined, thus nothing happens.

Comment: @KingCrunch think again (and read my answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code sample provides a security risk in case `register_globals` is on. In that case someone can pass `?variable=1` and your `if()` will be evaluated to true. It's best practice always to initialize your variables.

Comment: Ah, I remember when my old web host left register_globals on and ignored me when I warned them about it. Good times. +1

Comment: `register_globals` by itself did never pose a security risk. It only is if all code is *also* executed non-procedurally in the global scope. That's where they would show up. -- Always initializing vars is not overly practical and best practice, but anyway `r_g` are not a very current problem nowadays. (Should be a simple setup check & bail.)

Comment: @mario I meant that the provided code pose a security risk if register_globals is on. Why initializing vars is not best practise?

Comment: @Darhazer: Roger that. It obviously is for OPs code snippet. Albeit I assume it was simply too examplary-typoed. The assignment `$var =` and the `if ($variable)` probably referred to the same variable. Which case it wought have been 'initialized' already. For most commonplace processing constructs I would consider initialization an abuse of language and semantics. (If you were constantly treating a scripting lang like a compiled one, there is definitely something wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

You should always escape/strip all html entities from your tag anyway. It takes less than couple of seconds but it will help you in a long run if you worry about security risk.